# Unable to copy from vim to system clipboard

Tags: command-line, vim, clipboard

I am unable to copy from vim to system clipboard. Viceversa works, copying from outside vim and pasting with `p` is ok.

I have installed clipboard support, vim version is 7.3.429:

```
$ vim --version | grep clip
+clientserver +clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments 
+xsmp_interact +xterm_clipboard -xterm_save
```

I have:

```
set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

in my `.vimrc` and it is set when I do:

```
set clipboard?
```

or

```
:echo has('clipboard')
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and vim inside `gnome-terminal` (but also GVim has the same problem). Any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489428/how-to-make-vim-paste-from-and-copy-to-systems-clipboard This may help you out a bit.

Comment: Did you quit vim between typing "+y on visual selection and trying to paste outside vim ? It won't work if you do

Comment: @SamuelPeter No, I didn't quit vim

Comment: I ran into this issue because I was doing set `clipboard+=unnamedplus` something in the default setting was disabling it.  Changing to `clipboard=unnamedplus` (eg removing other settings) worked for me.

Comment: As @JonnyLeeds mentioned. The config `set clipboard+=unnamed` & `set clipboard+=unnamedplus` doesn't work while using **y** and **p** for share the system clipboard. `:set clipboard?` == `clipboard=autoselect,exclude:cons\|linux,unnamed,unnamedplus`; After I removed the first `+`, which is `set clipboard=unnamed` and `set clipboard+=unnamedplus`, and it works!! `:set clipboard?` == `clipboard=unnamed,unnamedplus`

Answer (score 113, accepted):

This is what works for me (Ubuntu 13.10):

Reinstall vim as vim-gtk:

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gtk
```

select what you want using the mouse - then type **to copy to clipboard**:

```
"+y
```

**to paste to vim from clipboard** type:

```
"+p
```

I don't know why but comparing the output of `vim --version` shows that the usual vim installation is quite restricted compared to vim-gtk. Replacing vim with vim-gtk did not affect any plugings.

---

Further information:

- [Vim on Ubuntu - cut to system clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101488/vim-on-ubuntu-cut-to-system-clipboard)
- [How to make vim paste from (and copy to) system's clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489428/how-to-make-vim-paste-from-and-copy-to-systems-clipboard)

Comment: Interestingly, on 14.04 both regular VIM and VIM-GTK have `xterm_clipboard` support, but `"+p` does not work in regular VIM. Rather than clipping to the clipboard, it increases the amont of selected lines.

Comment: Installing `vim-gtk` ultimately worked for me in 14.04.4, but I experienced things a bit differently than others commenting.  Prior to having `vim-gtk` installed, vim was showing `-xterm_clipboard` (i.e. not enabled).  After installing `vim-gtk` it shows (+xterm_clipboard). I am checking this with `vim --version | grep clip`.  Anyway, makes sense that you need `+xterm_clipboard`!

Comment: Any feedback from people on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Comment: I confirm that this fix still works with Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: not work if use windows terminal to ssh to Server and code in the server

Answer (score 7):

I am going to leave the original answer below because it may be important for others that search for this question.

In short there doesn't seem to be a one size fits all answer, but with 'set clipboard=unnamedplus'  one of either '*p' or '+p' should work from the "system" clipboard.

'*p' is almost certainly the one you want. ([from here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard))

---

vim is a cli program. When using it inside gnome-terminal (or any terminal emulator) crtl+c (or any key combination) is handled by the terminal emulator first, then the shell, then finally by the program (vim in this case). vim and ctrl+c will almost certainly never work because ctrl+c sends an SIGINT signal to the running task. vim uses SIGINT to stop other things like aborting insert mode, or stopping search functions.

In other words. Ctrl+C is never actually passed to VIM. SIGINT is passed to VIM. SIGINT has other uses in vim so using to copy is likely not going to work (and even if can you force it, not a good idea).

Instead try sticking with Ctrl+Shift+C and Ctrl+Shift+V (there are others but I believe those put text in the system clipboard)

To be fair I don't know much about gvim.

Comment: Maybe I confused you.. I said using `ctrl-c` OUTSIDE vim and the pasting with `p`, but in vim I know I have to use `y`.. I'll edit my question

Comment: LOL haven't had my caffeine yet, sorry.

Answer (score 5):

Use in your vimrc:

```
set mouse=a
```

It will allow you to select and copy manually with mouse.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [the accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/434994/466066), if you are working remotely over SSH (e.g. over `tmux` with multiple panes with different `vim` processes you want to copy between), you also need to export your X display since `vim` is using `xterm-clipboard` to interface between different processes. You can set the X display by running

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

This must be run **before** `vim` is launched, and under any other shell you have.

Answer (score 4):

I have found on Ubuntu 16.04 I need `vim-gui-common` installed in order for `"+y` to work.

Comment: Per the VIM docs, `:h registers`: _For Unix systems the clipboard
is only available when the **+xterm_clipboard** feature is present._ If you look at the `vim --version` output before and after installing `vim-gui-common`, you'll see that the `xterm_clipboard` feature gets added, which is what's needed. (aside: the `vim-gui-common` package is basically installing `gvim`)